# Database Schema - Many-to-Many Normalisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, many-to-many, database-schema

I'm designing a schema where a case can have many forms attached and a form can be used for many cases. The `Form` table basically holds the structure of a html form which gets rendered on the client side. When the form is submitted the name/value pairs for the fields are stored separately. Is there any value in keeping the name/value attributes seperate from the join table as follows?

```
CREATE TABLE Case (
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
); 

CREATE TABLE CaseForm (
   CaseID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Case (ID),
   FormID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Form (ID),
   CONSTRAINT PK_CaseForm PRIMARY KEY (CaseID, FormID)
); 

CREATE TABLE CaseFormAttribute (
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   CaseID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CaseForm (CaseID),
   FormID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CaseForm (FormID),
   Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   Value varchar(max)
); 

CREATE TABLE Form (
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   FieldsJson varchar (max) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm I overcomplicating the schema since the same many to many relationship can by achieved by turning the `CaseFormAttribute` table into the join table and getting rid of the `CaseForm` table altogether as follows?

```
CREATE TABLE CaseFormAttribute (
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   CaseID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Case (ID),
   FormID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Form (ID),
   Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   Value varchar(max) NULL
);
```

Basically what I'm trying to ask is which is the better design?

Comment: They would both work but it depends what tables you need. What is your ERD like?

Comment: Is there any benefit or value in having one over the other?

Comment: it depends whether you need the caseform table or not but i cant comment because i dont know your database design or requirements

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit of splitting up the two would depend on whether or not additional fields would ever be added to the CaseForm table. For instance, say that you want to record if a Form is incomplete. You may add an Incomplete bit field to that effect. Now, you have two main options for retrieving that information:

1. Clustered index scan on CaseForm
2. Create a nonclustered index on CaseForm.Incomplete which includes CaseID, FormID, and scan that

If you didn't split the tables, your two main options would be:

3. Clustered index scan on CaseFormAttribute
4. Create a nonclustered index on CaseFormAttribute.Incomplete which includes CaseID, FormID, and scan that

For the purposes of this example, query options 1 and 2 are roughly the same in terms of performance. Introducing the nonclustered index adds overhead in multiple ways. It's a little less streamlined than the clustered index (it may take more reads to scan in this particular example), it's additional storage space that CaseForm will take up, and the index has to be maintained for updates to the table. Option 4 will also perform similarly, with the same caveats as option 2. Option 3 will be your worst performer, as a clustered index scan will include reading all of the BLOB data in your Value field, even though it only needs the bit in Incomplete to determine whether or not to return that (Case, Form) pair.

So it really does depend on what direction you're going in the future.

Also, if you stay with the split approach, consider shifting CaseFormAttribute.ID to CaseForm, and then use CaseForm.ID as your PK/FK in CaseFormAttribute. The caveat here is that we're assuming that all Forms will be inserted at the same time for a given Case. If that's not true, then you would invite some page splits because your inserts will be somewhat random, though still generally increasing.

Comment: the requirement is one case can have multiple forms attached but not the same form. It needs to be a many to many relationship. So do I need to create a compound key using three columns (CaseId, FormId, Name)?

Comment: @adam78 I see it now - Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer accordingly. Your key is correct as is, and you should not include Name in the key.

Comment: no I think you are right - in my solution 2 I would end up with duplicate forms so I would need to add a unique key (CaseId, FormId, Name) in that instance.

Comment: @adam78 I see what you're saying. In solution 2, yes, you would want to add a unique key (assuming you don't drop the ID field altogether), but you could still leave Name out of it.